# attr_accessible, attr_accessor, I would like to know what they do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessible, attr-accessor

I'm doing my first steps in Rails and in object-oriented programming.
There is something quite fudemental that I would like to understand: why do we need `attr_accessible` within the model?

I have read that hackers can use mass-assignment in order to change database entries and therefore compremise security, and that's why sensitive fields need protection (using `atribute_protected` in this case).

Is `attr_accessible` the opposite of `atribute_protected`? If so, why do we need to state which fields are accessible and which are not? aren't those fields accessible by defult? And what is `attr_accessor` used for?

I noticed that if I don't make some fields acessible, my application doesn't run. Can I use attr_acessible for sensitive fields like :password_digest and :admin?

It would be amazing if someone could explain it to me.

All the best,
TimmyOnRails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of concepts mixed together here, so I'll try to untangle them.

`attr_accessor` is for setting up a readable and writable attribute. It is the equivalent of saying `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`. Since your question isn't directly about `attr_accessor`, I won't address it anymore than saying check out this link on [Accessors](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html).

---

According to the Rails docs: **`attr_accessible` is the opposite of the attr_protected macro**

You're correct that these methods are used to prevent Mass Assignment vulnerabilities.

- `attr_accessible` says which attributes **can** be set by mass assignment.
- `attr_protected` says which attributes **cannot** be set by mass assignment.

So what's the use case for each? In one case you're able to set a global config option that makes it so that all attributes must be declared `attr_accessible`:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

In that case you'd use `attr_accessible` frequently.

And `attr_protected`? If you went the opposite way and said `false` on whitelisting attributes, how would you declare which attributes shouldn't be mass assignable? If you said `attr_protected` you're right! :D

Typically you'd want to set fields like `:admin` as `attr_protected` because you don't want an attacker coming in and escalating their privileges to an admin role.

Mass assignment is not something that's easy to get right. Big, smart development teams have gotten this wrong. So tred carefully and make sure you understand what's going on!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much more clear now. I love this website!